# Can only have five bots in CS GO and competitive mode

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I would like to play alone (or with some friends) against 10 bots.
When selecting "casual", this is working pretty fine.
(The bots are only added to the CT team, there is no kind of team balancing, there is no check, if one team has more members than the other, maxplayers is set to 20)

But as soon as I switch to competitive mode, there are only 5 bots allowed. When trying to add one more bot to the CT team on the server console, a message is shown that the team be full.
I did not find any difference between the gamemode_casual cfg file and the gamemode_competitive file.

Does anyone have a clue why this phenomenon is shown?

Best regards,
Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this video:

I am unable to test it myself as I don't have access to CSGO at this moment in time, so apologies in advance if it doesn't work, but this video shows changing the gamemode files to increase the max players.

Good luck

Comment: That's it! Trank you!